# Can AppArmor restrict access to a specific interface?

Tags: bind, interface, apparmor

**A deceptively simple question;**

Can `Apparmor` on Ubuntu (any release) restrict network access for a specific application to a specific network interface?

If it can; an example/tutorial/etc link would be appreciated. Also what happens if the interface disappears (i.e. wifi is disabled etc.)?

If not; are there alternate solutions?

Cheers!
/ Daniel

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at the `ip` command, specifically this sub-command `netns`, i.e. `ip netns` for setting up namespaces and the associated `exec` parameter to `netns`.

```
$ ip netns help
Usage: ip netns list
       ip netns add NAME
       ip netns set NAME NETNSID
       ip [-all] netns delete [NAME]
       ip netns identify [PID]
       ip netns pids NAME
       ip [-all] netns exec [NAME] cmd ...
       ip netns monitor
       ip netns list-id
```

For example:

```
$ ip netns exec ....
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix SE :) Could you elaborate your answer with an example ?